# Power BI - Templates

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am using a Power BI trial account and creating a report in BI Desktop. The input data is not straightforward and i had to do few manipulation steps to arrive at my final table structured data.

I want to create templates for multiple users and the input data may or may not be in the same structure.
My question here is, is it possible to have a single/same template for different structured reports ?

As I mentioned,I am doing some kind of manipulations using query editor to arrive at the final rows and columns as of now. So by creating a template, should the user also need to do the same for his reports ?

And, if the reports are similarly structured, should the user again need to do use the query editors ?

Comment: If the datasource has the same columns and names, the template should work. If not, extra steps will be needed in Power Query to fix the discrepancies.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are applying some steps in Power Query (Massaging or Manipulating the data), the same should or should not to be followed.

The main point is that, each data has it's own structure, if the column names and the table name or files names are same, then no need to do anything .

However, if the data structure is different, then need to do it again.

Note: Power BI template always saves design (Like graphs, charts, KPI) or themes but not data. If input data would be different then it would show error on measures or columns.

Comment: So, templates can only be used for tables with similar columns and  structure. Am i right ?

Comment: Power BI report templates contain the following information from the report from which they were generated:

Report pages, visuals, and other visual elements
The data model definition, including the schema, relationships, measures, and other model definition artifacts
All query definitions, such as queries, Query Parameters, and other query elements
**What is not included in templates is the report's data.** So if you will supply different set of columns etc query won't be able to follow the steps and it would get fail.